# How to parse the table in this link using selenium / beautiful soup or similar?

Tags: python

I have tried to parse the data on this table:

https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?CodigoTipoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=62733

you will notice that this is a dynamically generated table (apparently javascript). It seems somehow that when I open the url using selenium or beautiful soup, it it's not possible to recognize / parse the table, although the table is there (if you right click on the table you and check frame source / page source you will see that they do not seem to be related).

please let me know if you are able to parse the table in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using selenium or any other library, once you look at the source, you'll find out that the table is being loaded inside an `iframe`, and the frame url, which is being set from javascript, is :

```
urlFrame = "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmDemonstracaoFinanceiraITR.aspx?Informacao=2&Demonstracao=4&Periodo=0&Grupo=DFs+Consolidadas&Quadro=Demonstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o+do+Resultado&NomeTipoDocumento=DFP&Titulo=Demonstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20do%20Resultado&Empresa=VALE%20S.A.&DataReferencia=31/12/2016&Versao=1&CodTipoDocumento=4&NumeroSequencialDocumento=62733&NumeroSequencialRegistroCvm=1789&CodigoTipoInstituicao=1"
```

but looks like this url needs some cookies which the browser automatically sends, so we'll first load our original url, then simply go to the frame url and extract the data from the table.

Solution using selenium :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?CodigoTipoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=62733"
urlFrame = "https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/enetconsulta/frmDemonstracaoFinanceiraITR.aspx?Informacao=2&Demonstracao=4&Periodo=0&Grupo=DFs+Consolidadas&Quadro=Demonstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o+do+Resultado&NomeTipoDocumento=DFP&Titulo=Demonstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20do%20Resultado&Empresa=VALE%20S.A.&DataReferencia=31/12/2016&Versao=1&CodTipoDocumento=4&NumeroSequencialDocumento=62733&NumeroSequencialRegistroCvm=1789&CodigoTipoInstituicao=1"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
driver.get(urlFrame)

print(driver.page_source)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

table_data = soup.findAll("table", {"id": "ctl00_cphPopUp_tbDados"})
# do something with table_data/ parse it further
print(table_data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ashish. All the best